# Plotting off edge of axis when limits changed

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

I've found a super weird bug in Spyder / matplotlib where my graph is going off the edge of the graph whenever I set the limits to smaller than the graph range. I have updated to the latest anaconda-supported versions of everything (Spyder 5.1.5, Python 3.8.12), and it has persisted across versions.

I've pared it down to a minimum use-case, and it persists even when I restart the terminal.  It also persists when I have a single subplot axis, but I wanted to show both here for comparison. (Note that `fig.tight_layout()` doesn't help)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0,100)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

#plots y=x line from 0 to 100
axs[1,0].plot(x)

#shrink the limits
axs[1,0].set_xlim(0,10)
axs[1,0].set_ylim(0,10)
```

[image: simple plot off edge of graph]

**My current install** (as of 2/8/2022, when I ran through the update process)

- Spyder version: 5.1.5 None
- Python version: 3.8.12 64-bit
- Qt version: 5.12.10
- PyQt5 version: 5.12.3
- Operating System: Windows 10

**Alternate Code Sample**

Here's another version of the same problem.  There are two plots of the same graph `y = 1/x`, where the second one has the ylim shrunk

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0.001,0.5,1000)

#creating the figure with 2 rows
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=2, figsize=(7,4), dpi=600)    

#plot data automatically
axs[0].scatter(x,1/x,s=1)

#same thing, but with axis truncated to 50
axs[1].scatter(x,1/x,s=1, c='r')
axs[1].set_ylim(0,10)
```

[image: red line goes out of bounds of plot]

Note: apologies for repost; I came back to the problem after several months with cleaner, new examples, and updated, but the edited old post was receiving no traction.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue on my system - I get this: https://i.imgur.com/jdnooQy.png I'm using OS X, Spyder 4.1.5, and Python 3.8.1 if that helps.

Comment: I really don't understand it.  I've updated everything.  I suppose the next thing is attempting to reinstall Anaconda entirely.  But I've never seen that bug ever, and now it's durable on my system.

Comment: I have uninstalled Anaconda/Spyder and reinstalled and the problem is still there.